# TableListener java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My table has 3 operations 1) add 2) delete 3) update status.

where 1 and 2 are Jbuttonsl

when I click 1)add a new row is added

when I click 2) delete the row is added.

1 and 2) are working as i set, but for updating status in last column, I coded in this way

```
public void statusUpd() throws SQLException
{
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) 
            {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(!(row<0))
                {
                    String name=(String)(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0));
                    String status = (String)(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3));
                    String update = "UPDATE "+deptName+ " SET Status = ? WHERE Name = ?";
                    try 
                    {
                        conn = ac.getConnection();
                        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(update);

                        stmt.setString(1, status);
                        stmt.setString(2, name);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();                            
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try
                        {               
                            if(stmt != null){stmt.close();}
                            if(conn != null) {conn.close();}
                        }
                        catch(SQLException e){}
                     }
                }
            }
        });


}
```

But this method listens when the add or delete button is clicked, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: whatever you do, _don't_ change the model in a modelListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableModelEvent` has a [getType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html#getType%28%29) method with which you can find the type of operation. So you could have in your code at the beginning of the `tableChanged` method:

```
if(tme.getType() != TableModelEvent.INSERT
        && tme.getType() != TableModelEvent.DELETE)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

or equivalently

```
if(tme.getType() != TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not the best way to do it, but you could add a class variable to indicate that you just clicked a button.

```
boolean buttonClicked = false;
```

When you click add or delete, set it to true, and then place this at the beginning of your update code:

```
if(buttonClicked){
  buttonClicked = false;
  return;
}
```

Comment: The basic design is wrong, your solution is even more wrong. Advising to use `static` is just the worst.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - Could you please explain why this is wrong?  I haven't worked with JTable before, but I have used this type of solution in my own code with no problems.  I give this answer with the assumption that all relevant code is located within the same class.

Comment: The original problem is that `TableModelListener` are not a good way to synchronize various models together. There are 2 good ways to do that: 1) do it all in a custom `TableModel` 2) Create a real "Model" and make a `TableModel` which is an adapter on that "Model". Whichever is chosen, the ugly hack that you suggest won't have to be done. The use of `static` variables is a very bad habit that many people tend to use.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - You're right, I definitely shouldn't have the static.  That's a habit I've gotten into because the majority of my classes only have one instance and run from the main method.  That being said, I don't think that my solution is wrong when the static is removed.  It might be a bit ugly, and there may be better answers using the TableModel functionality (which I haven't used), but if things are synchronized properly it shouldn't cause problems.